# Bootstrap Typeahead : How to get all fetched remote values in typeahead bind function

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead, twitter-typeahead

Is it possible to get all fetched remote values in typeahead bind function?

```
var bankNames = new Bloodhound({
         datumTokenizer: function (datum) {
            return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(datum.value);
         },
         queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
         limit: 10,
         remote: {
            url: '/payments/bankwithdrawal/bankdetails?str=%QUERY,
            prepare: function (query, settings) {
               var encoded = query.toUnicode();
               settings.url = settings.url.replace('%QUERY', encoded);
               return settings;
            }
         }
      });

      bankNames.initialize();

      // Initializing the typeahead
      $('.typeahead').typeahead({
                 hint: true,
                 highlight: true, // Enable substring highlighting
                 minLength: 1 // Specify minimum characters required for showing result
              },
              {
                 name: 'bankname',
                 source: bankNames
              }).bind('change blur', function () {

                console.log(bankNames);

                console.log(bankNames.index.datums);

    });
```

It should give me all bankNames in `bankNames.index.datums` but it is giving me

```
Object {}
__proto__: Object
constructor: function Object()
hasOwnProperty: function hasOwnProperty()
isPrototypeOf: function isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable: function propertyIsEnumerable()
toLocaleString: function toLocaleString()
toString: function toString()
valueOf: function valueOf()
__defineGetter__: function __defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__: function __defineSetter__()
__lookupGetter__: function __lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__: function __lookupSetter__()
get __proto__: function __proto__()
set __proto__: function __proto__()
```

I need all bankNames in bind function where I need to perform some action.

When I am printing in bind function `console.log(bankNames)` it should return me all fetched remote values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution with the help of `transform` which is a part of `Bloodhound`.
When configuring remote option, the `transform` options is available.

> transform – A function with the signature transform(response) that
>   allows you to transform the remote response before the Bloodhound
>   instance operates on it.

You can read more about Bloodhound option in this link
https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md#remote

```
var bankNameList;
var bankNames = new Bloodhound({
         datumTokenizer: function (datum) {
            return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(datum.value);
         },
         queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
         limit: 10,
         remote: {
            url: '/payments/bankwithdrawal/bankdetails?str=%QUERY,
            prepare: function (query, settings) {
               var encoded = query.toUnicode();
               settings.url = settings.url.replace('%QUERY', encoded);
               return settings;
            },
            transform : function (data) {
               bankNameList = data;
               return data;
            }
         }
      });

      bankNames.initialize();

      // Initializing the typeahead
      $('.typeahead').typeahead({
                 hint: true,
                 highlight: true, // Enable substring highlighting
                 minLength: 1 // Specify minimum characters required for showing result
              },
              {
                 name: 'bankname',
                 source: bankNames
              }).bind('change blur', function () {

                console.log(bankNameList);

      });
```

Now If you print bankNameList inside `bind` function of typeahead `console.log(bankNameList);` It will print data which is fetched from remote.